# Sql Query Returns Object

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sql = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE username='$User'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if($result->num_rows > 0){
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            $email = $row["email"];
        }
    }
    echo $email;
    require_once("class.phpmailer.php");;
    $email = new PHPMailer();
    $email->From = "clientinformation@apbdispatch.com";
    $email->Subject = "$from";
    $email->AddAddress("$email");
```

When echoing $email, it returns the persons email address. However, when putting it in double quotes, I get an error message stating that an object cannot be converted into a string.

Thanks for your help,

aimmmmmmmmm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spot the problem:

retrieve the email:

```
        $email = $row["email"];
```

instantiate your mailer:

```
$email = new PHPMailer();
  ^---oops, now your database result is destroyed.
```

Comment: Woops! Well then, thanks for the help.